# Rails: helper returns correct SQL result but ignores columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a helper in my ApplicationHelper file that works just fine:

```
def latest_issue
  @issue = Issue.find(:all, :order => "id DESC", :limit => 1)
  return @issue
end
```

After that, using `@issue` works just fine in any view, but considering that `@issue` has a column named `message` using `@issue.message` returns a No Method Error.

Any help would be fantastic! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue instance variable is returning an array of objects not an instance. If you would like to select an attribute of an Issue object you need to return an instance of the object.

```
 @issue = Issue.find(:last)
 @issue.message
```

You may be trying to output all the message attributes of the Issue object, if that is the case you need to pass the @issue to an block

```
 @issue.each do  |issue|
   issue.message
 end
```

Comment: That works great, cheers! But that'll always select the issue with an ID of 1, right? And not get the latest issue?

Comment: You can use Issue.find(:first, :order => "id DESC")

Comment: Also, its more Rails 3 if you write it like this Issue.order("id desc").first , using the find with conditions is decremented

Answer (score 2):

As [Kyle C says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11945830/229044), you're attempting to access the member `message` of an *array* of Issues, when you should be returning a single issue from your helper.

Assuming you're using Rails 3, A vastly improved version of your helper would be written this way:

```
def latest_issue
  Issue.order(:id).last
end
```

A few notes on writing idomatic Ruby:

- Avoid explicit  `return` statements, and let the last statement be the return value of a method
- Use the chainable methods like `order()`, `where()`, and `limit()` instead of passing arguments to `find`

Comment: Thanks for the notes! I'm rather new to this, I'm sure you can tell.